# Flurry send test push message stopped working

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, flurry

In my project sending Flurry campaigns to a specific iOS device using Push Token stopped working suddenly.

I have previously configured Flurry with an Apple Push Services certificate for production and an Apple Development iOS Push Services for development. Both certificates are still valid.

When trying to send the push message to my device using Push Token, we get this error message:

> Unable to send test push. Please try again

I'm at a loss what the error could be here, especially since it worked fine before. Any ideas?

Comment: Most failures generate specific messages, but sometimes(as it appears above), the failure message is generic. Can you email support@flurry.com with the details of which app this was for, and roughly what day/time you tried the test push?

Comment: @FlurryAnalyticsSupport We still haven't received any help from you guys after you received the additional information. How long should can we expect to wait? regarding support ticket 140521

Comment: I've sent an update to you regarding your case. We're still investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some weeks Flurry support managed to solve this. Meaning we did not have any faulty configurations.